# How to retrieve email alert used in flow in VS?

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, email-alert, sfdx-plugin

I have created an email alert which is being used in flow. I am trying to retrieve that email alert in VS code, using `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m workflowAlert` command.

But I am not able to retrieve email alert, could anyone guide me here what is wrong in this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WorkflowAlert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm#WorkflowAlert) is within the [Workflow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm) metadata which is encompassed per object

> This metadata type represents the valid types of workflow rules and
> actions associated with a standard or custom object.

As a result, you can't retrieve all `WorkflowAlert` metadata in the org since they'd be across all different `Workflow` metadata containers across all objects. However, you could just retrieve `Workflow`

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Workflow`

Which, assuming your local/org were exact until you made changes, will only return what was changed in your org which should be the addition of an email alert on the given object it's on.

However, similar to when utilizing a package.xml, you can retrieve a specific email alert in the following format

`ObjectName.EmailAlertName`

In sfdx, the command would look like

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m WorkflowAlert:Object__c.Email_Alert_Name`

Answer (score 0):

I used sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Workflow:Opportunity for the opportunity object and it worked for all email alerts.

Answer (score -1):

XML TAG Example:

```
<types>
    <members>Case.Case_Assignment_Notification</members>
    <name>WorkflowAlert</name>
</types>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/196872)